# Dynamically set enablePersistence() with angularfire2

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Currently angularfire2 allows you draw from cached data by importing `AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()`in app.module file.

I'm wondering if it's possible (and how) to do this dynamically after the app has been initialized.

The reason i'm trying to do this, is currently enablePersistence only works on one tab in a browser, but works great for mobile. I would love to just disable it for the web and have it enabled for mobile.

Currently i'm using Ionic for development just in case that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From the [reference documentation for `enablePersistence()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#enablePersistence):

> Must be called before any other methods (other than `settings()`).

So you can enable persistence, as long as you haven't made any other Firestore calls.

Comment: Awesome, i'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to dynamically call enablePersistence() with angularfire2 though. Any chance you can add some how here?